# Could not receive a message from the daemon

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to setup Jenkins multibranch pipeline that uses Jenkins file.
The project I'm configuring is built using gradle and on the jenkins file, I have the following snippet

`stage('build')
   sh "./gradlew build --stacktrace"`

And every time I run the build, it always fail with the error below. I've tried to disable gradle daemon, but it keeps showing the same error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not receive a message from the daemon.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonConnectionException: Could not receive a message from the daemon.
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:81)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.monitorBuild(DaemonClient.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:178)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:141)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:285)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:258)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:251)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:185)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.RecoverableMessageIOException: Could not read message from '/127.0.0.1:33449'.
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection.receive(DaemonClientConnection.java:75)
... 29 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: ED000573
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
at org.gradle.internal.io.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.<init>(ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.ExceptionReplacingObjectInputStream.<init>(ExceptionReplacingObjectInputStream.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Message.receive(Message.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.BaseSerializerFactory$ThrowableSerializer.read(BaseSerializerFactory.java:240)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.BaseSerializerFactory$ThrowableSerializer.read(BaseSerializerFactory.java:238)
at org.gradle.internal.logging.serializer.LogEventSerializer.read(LogEventSerializer.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.logging.serializer.LogEventSerializer.read(LogEventSerializer.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:144)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.DaemonMessageSerializer$OutputMessageSerializer.read(DaemonMessageSerializer.java:147)
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.DaemonMessageSerializer$OutputMessageSerializer.read(DaemonMessageSerializer.java:133)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.DefaultSerializerRegistry$TaggedTypeSerializer.read(DefaultSerializerRegistry.java:144)
at org.gradle.internal.serialize.Serializers$StatefulSerializerAdapter$1.read(Serializers.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection.receive(SocketConnection.java:79)
... 30 more
```

Answer (score 26):

Is your mobile hotspot enabled? if you use de windows 10 mobile hotspot brings the error in my computer, disabled and try it, run normally.

Comment: I was having this same issue in Android Studio using Flutter. Thank you!

Comment: That was exactly the problem... hostpot enabled, thank you

Comment: I don't know why but its work ‍♂️, thank you

Answer (score 2):

1. of all: which gradle version (I got this since upgrading from 4.7 to 4.9, but your post is much older)
2. please try to build without daemon, i.e.

   ```
   sh "./gradlew --no-daemon build -s"
   ```
3. this should indicate what is the error cause, typically (my observation) there are errors thrown in (custom)plugins or scripts of initialization phase (buildSrc)

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to find root cause.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error caused by VMware software.
If you are using Windows 10, and also using VMware or have downloded it recently, here's my solution:

1. Open the Task Manager.
2. Terminate all about VMware services.

Answer (score 0):

Set `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable with value `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

Command for Windows: `set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Source: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/16996#issuecomment-910296681

Answer (score -2):

close your computer Hot spot and try again

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65243109/2227743).