# Could not receive a message from the daemon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle, daemon

I know this message has been already asked before but none of the answers has fixed my issue,

The error message:

[image]

I have already tried disabling the hotspot of my emulator (which is a Pixel XL API 30) but it doesn't work. I have also tried restarting my pc, IDE and emulator and also changing my IDE from vs code to Android Studio but the error doesn't go away. I am new to flutter and I don't want to give up at the start!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEVWb_8XmLU

Comment: watch this video

Comment: @kkweb tried but it doesn't work and the error message is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I said I couldn't find any solutions but here it is:
**delete ANY VMware processes or, if you can, unistall VMware and use virtualbox instead**, even if vmware is not running it will confict with other emulators.

[Credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69371251/17292719)

Answer (score 2):

Disable your mobile hotspot. If you use  windows 11 that was my error  try, will  run normally easy like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the Windows Hotspot Wifi as "@Salah dine Maham" said.
As I know it is related to a gradle issue (shows up from about gradle v6.3), I went to the

```
android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

I updated the distributionURL into :

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-all.zip
```

You "may" need to update the gradle plugin on the android project.
And now you can debug again freely through Windows Hotspot wifi.